# How can one make the beam angle smaller on an ultrasonic sensor?

Tags: sensors

I'm trying to create higher resolution data with a beam angle of 5> degrees (as close as 1 degree as possible). I have been experimenting with creating using an aluminum casing around the sensor input. Are there any other or perhaps better ways of doing this?

[CH201 datasheet](http://invensense.tdk.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/DS-000379-CH201-v1.1.pdf?ref_disty=digikey).

Comment: What are the specification for sensor? Can you share some images?

Comment: Datasheet: http://invensense.tdk.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/DS-000379-CH201-v1.1.pdf?ref_disty=digikey

Answer (score 1):

Consider something like the following. Use 3D printer to experiment.

[image]

### [image]

---

**Reference:**

- [EV_MOD_CH201 Evaluation Module User Guide](https://3cfeqx1hf82y3xcoull08ihx-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/AN-000232-EV_MOD_CH201-Evaluation-Module-User-Guide-v1.0.pdf)
- [CH201 Mechanical Integration Guide](https://www.mouser.com/pdfDocs/AN-000221-CH201-Mechanical-Integration-Guide-v10.pdf)

Comment: That image is for a 45" beam profile. The OP is requesting less than 5 degrees.

Comment: @EricS  You are correct, I am providing OP an idea, to achieve 5 degree's. Currently OP is using an aluminum casing.

Answer (score 0):

The datasheet, page 11, says:

> CH201 Beam Patterns

> The acoustic Field of View is easily customizable for the CH201 and is achieved by adding an acoustic housing to the transceiver that
> is profiled to realize the desired beam pattern. Symmetric, asymmetric, and omnidirectional (180° FoV) beam patterns are realizable.

An example beam pattern is shown in the Typical Operating Characteristics section of this document and several acoustic housing
designs for various FoV’s are available from Chirp.

Talk to them!

Comment: Some sort of link would help this answer.

Comment: The OP has the link buried in the comments.

Comment: Please put it in your answer. You shouldn’t make people search for important information.

Comment: I put it in the question where it should have been. Thanks.

Comment: I still think it is best embedded in your answer since you are referring it. You might think it is redundant, but why make the reader search?